# 500 internal server error for 301 redirect in web config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, http-redirect

```
    <rewrite>
     <rules>
     <rule name="301Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
      <add input="{old:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
       </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" 
       redirectType="Permanent" />
       </rule>
      </rules>
     <rewriteMaps>
     <rewriteMap name="old">
    <add key="/formlocation/form.html?querystring1" value="/pages/page.aspx" />
 <add key="/formlocation/form.html?querystring2" value="/pages/page.aspx" />
  <add key="/formlocation/form.html?querystring3" value="/pages/page.aspx" />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
  </rewrite>
```

I am using this code in my web .config to redirect a page and getting a 500 internal servor error. Any clue why?

Comment: what actually are you trying to do?

Comment: redirect from form.html to the aspx page

Comment: @Webruster it appears that the problem is with using the query string parameters.. otherwise the redirect rule works.

Comment: @Webruster i have updated with the code i have used..hope its clear now